# cannot access netcore apps in docker ubuntu container

Tags: ubuntu, .net-core, containers, docker-desktop

thanks for your time.
I cannot access my netcore app in docker ubuntu container, any helps will be much appreciated!

1. I installed docker desktop on windows 11, and pulled ubuntu:22.04 image, and running it, container named **ubuntu**.
2. I made a dir /www to put my apps. and also installed .net SDK.

```
# dotnet --version
6.0.110
```

3. I created an application of netcore webapi(.net 6, very simple), and published. and copied to the /www.

```
D:\GIT Publish>docker cp demo\ ubuntu:/www/
```

4. run dotnet app by the command.

```
# dotnet Demo.dll --urls="http://*:8081;http://*:8082"
info: Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime[14]
      Now listening on: http://[::]:8081
info: Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime[14]
      Now listening on: http://[::]:8082
info: Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime[0]
      Application started. Press Ctrl+C to shut down.
info: Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime[0]
      Hosting environment: Production
info: Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime[0]
      Content root path: /www/demo/
warn: Microsoft.AspNetCore.HttpsPolicy.HttpsRedirectionMiddleware[3]
      Failed to determine the https port for redirect.
```

5. I used this command to find the ubuntu vm ip address:172.17.0.2

```
docker inspect ubuntu
```

```
"Networks": {
            "bridge": {
                "IPAMConfig": null,
                "Links": null,
                "Aliases": null,
                "NetworkID": "8fe0bc477b1cb2af65cac412418ab0af11ba36fe49ecf5818b7f5f40fa6a14d7",
                "EndpointID": "56e23d2cef246bbf27ed279d80aa8a0240460744aa1d60c549b1f1ed8a50f41e",
                "Gateway": "172.17.0.1",
                "IPAddress": "172.17.0.2",
                "IPPrefixLen": 16,
                "IPv6Gateway": "",
                "GlobalIPv6Address": "",
                "GlobalIPv6PrefixLen": 0,
                "MacAddress": "02:42:ac:11:00:02",
                "DriverOpts": null
            }
        }
```

6. It works fine when I access my app by commands in external terminal:

```
curl http://localhost:8081
```

or

```
curl http://172.17.0.2:8081
```

Everything is OK by now, but when I tried to access the app on my local window browser(google chrome) through url: http://172.17.0.2:8081 or http://172.17.0.2:8082, Unable to access this site and timeout.

So how do I access the app in the ubuntu container on my windows host? I googled a lot but no helps, am I missed something? or some configuration between ubuntu and my local windows host? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Have you exposed ports 8081 and 8082 when you created docker container?

Comment: No, but I tried to do this, the ubuntu container cannot be started anymore.

Comment: 1. docker commit ubuntu c_ubuntu:1.0 / 2. docker run --name ubuntu01 -p 8081:8081 c_ubuntu:1.0        here is my commands,

Comment: I finally to use the docker file to gen docker image immediately(visual studio docker support).